# Stuck in grub rescue limbo- Please help

Tags: boot, grubrescue, data-recovery

I installed ubuntu about a year ago and yesterday I deleted the partition, because my parents were annoyed with the startup menu. I didn't know that I had to fix the 'mbr'.

Now every time I try to boot the computer the grub menu pops up and says that the partition  cannot be found. I made an ubuntu dvd but it doesn't turn on automatically and I have no clue how to do it manually.

Please help me, I have no clue what to do.
Could someone at least tell me how to retrieve data or documents.

Comment: Could there be any way to delete grub so that I go straight to windows?

Answer (score 0):

If your PC manufacturer gave you a Windows installation CD, you can use it to `Repair` your current Windows installation (don't re-install, or you'll lose everything).  If you want to get your data onto another drive, or reinstall Ubuntu, you can use the Ubuntu CD you said you have.

Booting your computer from a CD can be a different process depending on the manufacturer, and the BIOS version.  I suggest searching for `how to boot from cd on [computer manufacturer/model number here]`, so you can get some specific help.  Tip: Most of the time, you can press `F2` before the BIOS hands control to GRUB, and you'll get the CMOS settings page.  From there, you can change the boot order so that CD will be the default.

Edit: Yes, this is absolutely a duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu, but Windows back on.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: I tried that. but when I rebooted the desktop and the grub menu came up again this time it said "An operating system wasn't found. try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system. press any key to restart." what do I do now. the only external drives I have on it is the dvd.

Comment: @Jyot, which part did you try?  And just to be sure, did you install this system from CD, or DVD?  Older systems often refuse to boot from a DVD, I've found.

Comment: I tried using a windows installation dvd. I think it's bootable 'cause I got it with the dell.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help unless I know exactly where it's not working - first, were you able to boot into the Windows install disk at all?  If not, did you find the Boot Options menu in you CMOS settings, and it still says there's no OS?  You say you made an Ubuntu DVD - is this the same disk from which you installed the Linux installation you just removed, or did you burn it recently?

Comment: Sorry for not responding immediately and thank you all for your help. I downloaded the ubuntu boot-repair software and burned it onto a cd as an img file using imgburn (a free software tool), then I changed the cd to the first option in the boot menu and it actually worked!